# HTML5 WebSocket connection type

Tags: javascript, html, websocket, telnet

I am trying to demonstrate the use of the HTML5 websocket. The following code works using the WebSocket.org echo server. But i am looking to connect to a different resource. I can for example use putty/telnet to connect to a dictionary server "dict.org" on port: 2628 and look up words. So my question is can i use WebSocket to connect to this type of resource and if so, how?
Thank You.

```
<pre>

    window.onload = function () {
        var btnConnect = document.getElementById("btnConnect");
        var btnDisconnect = document.getElementById("btnDisconnect");
        var btnSend = document.getElementById("btnSend");

        btnConnect.onclick = function () {
            socket = new WebSocket("ws://echo.websocket.org/");
            //socket = new WebSocket('ws://dict.org:2628');
            outPut("Connecting...");
            socket.onopen = function () {
                outPut("Socket Connection Established.");
            }
            socket.onclose = function () {
                outPut("Socket Closed.");
            }
            socket.onmessage = function (evt) {
                outPut("[Server Msg]: " + evt.data);
            }
            socket.onerror = function (err) {
                outPut("[Error]: " + err.data);
            }
            btnDisconnect.onclick = function () {
                if (socket.readyState != WebSocket.OPEN) return;
                outPut("Disconnected...");
                socket.close();
            }
            btnSend.onclick = function () {
                if (socket.readyState != WebSocket.OPEN) return;
                var strClient = document.getElementById("strClient").value;
                socket.send(strClient);
                outPut("[Client Msg]: " + strClient);
            }
        }  
    }
    function outPut(str) {
        var txtServer = document.getElementById("txtServer");
        txtServer.value += "\n " + str;
    }

</pre>
```

Comment: I don't see any websocket server on that port. The connection never success.

Answer (score 0):

> can i use WebSocket to connect to this type of resource and if so, how?

Not directly. Yes with a WebSocket to plain TCP proxy.

To open a WS connection you need to Upgrade an HTTP connection. When you ask the browser to open a WS connection, it sends an Upgrade command to the HTTP server (Apache, nginx, etc.), which redirects the connection to the WS server you have configured. The latter can be written in Python, node.js, C, etc. and needs to understand and follow the WebSocket protocol.

If you want to communicate with dict.org through WS, my suggestion would be to create a WS proxy server that takes commands from the WS side, converts them to plain text TCP requests on dict.org:2628 and then forwards the answer back to the client.